# Methods "matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled" and "matchmakerViewController" not being called inside of GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit

I am making a real time multiplayer game with swift, SpriteKit and most importantly GameKit, however I am fairly new to swift and swift UI.

I have initialized my `GKMatchmakerViewController` with a `GKrequest`, and believe that I have set that particular view controller's delegate to be the view controller it is inside of. Doing this required me to conform the larger view controller to the protocol of `GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate` which gave me the functions `matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled` and `matchmakerViewController:didFailWithError:` which should be called when either I cancel out of the matchmaking controller or it crashes with an error.

My problem is that neither of these functions seem to be getting called unless I do it manually. I am not entirely sure if I have properly set the controller delegate, which I believe to be the root of the problem, however if anyone has any, more experienced, insight I would gladly appreciate it. The conforming View Controller's code is shown below. All help is appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import GameKit

let request = GKMatchRequest()

class SecondScreenViewController : UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate {

    let button = UIButton()
    let softRed = UIColor(red: 1, green: 61 / 255, blue: 61 / 255, alpha: 1)
    let softblue = UIColor(red: 38 / 255, green: 149 / 255, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    
    let TestMatchMaker = GKMatchmaker()
    let TestMatch = GKMatch()
    var TestViewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupButton()
        SetupRequest()
        view.backgroundColor = softblue
    }
    
    func matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController) {
       dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        
    }
    
    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFind match: GKMatch) {
        print("yess")
    }
    
    func SetupRequest() {
        request.minPlayers = 2
        request.maxPlayers = 2
        request.inviteMessage = "test Invite"
    }

    
    func setupButton() {
         button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
         button.setTitleColor(softblue, for: .normal)
         button.setTitle("MatchMake", for: .normal)
         button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
         
         view.addSubview(button)
         setupButtonConstraints()
     }
     
     func setupButtonConstraints() {
         button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
         button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
         button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
         button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
         
     }
     
     @objc func ButtonTapped() {
        
        
        present(TestViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        TestViewController!.delegate = self
        
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. After some research into GKMatchmakerViewController it turned out that you have to set the .matchmakerDelegate instead of .delegate in the makeUIViewController method of your UIViewControllerRepresentable.

```
import SwiftUI
import GameKit

struct MatchmakerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let matchRequest = GKMatchRequest()
        
        ///Set up the match request according to the game
        matchRequest.minPlayers = 2
        matchRequest.maxPlayers = 4
        matchRequest.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2
        matchRequest.inviteMessage = "CustomInviteMessage"
                    
        guard let matchmakerVC = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: matchRequest) else {
            #warning("Implement AlertViewController if match could not be created")
            return UIViewController()
        }
        
        matchmakerVC.matchmakerDelegate = context.coordinator
        
        return matchmakerVC
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        init(_ parent: MatchmakerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        var parent: MatchmakerView
        
        func matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController) {
            viewController.dismiss(animated: true)
        }
        
        func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            //Implement error handling
            fatalError("MatchMakingVC failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the Apple documentation regarding this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkmatchmakerviewcontroller/1492426-matchmakerdelegate